# Aggregate Function Mongoose - Node

Tags: node.js, mongoose, serverless

I have a schema

```
const membershipsSchema = new Schema({
  spaceId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Space',
  },
  member: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  ....
);

mongoose.model('Membership', membershipsSchema);
```

I want to use join statement like

```
Select * from membershipPlans as plans join User as users on plans.member=users._id
where plans.spaceId=id and users.status <> 'archived'; // id is coming from function arguments
```

I tried the `aggregate` pipeline like

```
const memberships = await Memberships.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      spaceId: id
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'User',
      localField: 'member',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'users',
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      'users.status': {$ne: 'archived'}
    }
  },
]);
```

But on `console.log(memberships);` I am getting an empty array. If I try `return Memberships.find({ spaceId: id })` it returns populated memberships of that space. But when I try

```
const memberships = await Memberships.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      spaceId: id
    }
  },
]}
```

**It still returns an empty array**. Not sure if I know how to use an `aggregate` pipeline.

Comment: Is `id`an ObjectId or a String?

Comment: The `id` coming from the function arguments is `string`. But in schema we have of type `Schema.Types.ObjectId`.

Comment: Then you need to cast it to ObjectId in aggregate, like this `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)`

Comment: You mean like `spaceId: new Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)`?

Comment: I tried it, but getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ObjectId')` exception.

Comment: m should be small for mongoose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249582/discussion-between-junaid-and-charchit-kapoor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that you need to do:

1. Cast `id` to `ObjectId`.
2. Instead of using `$match`, just filter the contents of the `users` array using $filter.

Try this:

```
const memberships = await Memberships.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      spaceId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'User',
      localField: 'member',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'users',
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      users: {$filter: {
         input: "$users",
         as: "user",
         cond: {
           $ne: ["$$user.status", "archived"]
         }
      }}
    }
  },
]);
```

Comment: I changed `from: 'User',` to `from: 'users',`, and it worked.